# convert object into array of objects with additional properties in it

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, json, object

I have below code of data. It is an object and each key has a date to it. There are properties `Open` and `Closed` within it. If `Closed` is 0, then that property is not present.

```
let data = {
          "2021-09-06": {
            "Open": 24
          },
          "2021-09-07": {
            "Open": 80,
            "Closed": 14
          },
        }
```

I want to achieve the following

```
let res = [
          { "date": "2021-09-06", "Open": 24, "Closed": 0 },
          { "date": "2021-09-07", "Open": 80, "Closed": 14 },
        ]
```

Can someone please let me know how to achieve this. I have tried this way but i dont get `date` property within the object as i want.

```
Object.entries(data).map((e) => ( { [e[0]]: e[1] } ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track.

`Object.entries()` returns an array of `[key, value]` tuples, so in your case each entry will look something like `['2021-09-06', { Open: 24,}]`.

You can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) this passed tuple in the `map()` call which makes it more descriptive.

```
Object.entries(data).map(([date, value]) => ...
```

You can then use [shorthand asignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) to create the `date` property, declare a default `Closed: 0` property, and then use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to apply the existing properties of the `value` object which will overwrite the `Closed` property if it exists in the original.

```js
let data = { 
  '2021-09-06': { Open: 24, },
  '2021-09-07': { Open: 80, Closed: 14, },
};

const result = Object.entries(data).map(([date, value]) => ({ date, Closed: 0, ...value }));

console.log(result);
```